# Easily pretty print XML

Tags: formatting, xml

Is there a way to quickly pretty print large XML files without needing an app? Online solutions don't allow for massive files and I'd like to do this without install more junk on my computer.

Answer (score 33):

Macs come with `libxml2` which inclues a tool called `xmllint`. You can use this to format your xml with ease. The tool does not have a graphical interface, so you'll need to fire up terminal.

Example 1. Format a file

```
xmllint --format - < file_to_format.xml > formatted_output.xml
```

Example 2. Format xml from clipboard

```
pbpaste | xmllint --format - > formatted_output.xml
```

Comment: The link to the blog is no longer valid.  The rest of this answer is correct and useful.

Comment: Very helpful, in deed. And after 7 years, I assume no other answer will come in, and you could consider accepting your own answer ;-) ... thank you very much!